How to extract and plot band structure data without XMGRACE from CASTEP output?
I am running CASTEP band structure calculations on our HPC but do not have XMGRACE installed to plot the results. I want to extract the data and plot it using other tools like Origin. I’ve used dispersion.pl to process the data, but I am unsure how to find the X and Y data needed to plot the band structure.
Specifically:
How can I extract the X (k-point) and Y (energy) values for plotting?
How can I identify the position of high symmetry points in the data for labeling the plot correctly?
Any guidance on how to process the output files from CASTEP and organize the data for plotting would be appreciated. Thank you!

The Perl scripts dispersion.pl and dos.pl are mostly intended as quick, lightweight plotting. They can launch xmgrace or gnuplot directly (depending which option you give), and are great for quick visualisation without needing lots of other libraries to be installed. However, they are not very sophisticated and will only do basic plots, smearing etc. If you really want to use them for an Origin plot, the best option is probably to use the "no plot" mode (-np) and write the data directly to a file.
For more sophisticated plotting options, tools like optados, euphonic or sumo are usually better and available freely; eg sumo is available at:
https://smtg-bham.github.io/sumo/
